# Command line tool to search docx file under ms dos or cygwin

Tags: linux, search, command-line, docx

Is there a command line tool that is able to search docx file under ms dos or cygwin ?

I have tried grep, it's not working with docx while working fine with txt file.

I know I could always convert the docx to txt 1st then search using grep, but I am wondering

is there a command tool that I can search directly under command line?

Thanks

Comment: If this is gonne be closed bcos offtopic can you comment where should I put this question ?

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, please try  http://superuser.com/ .  (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: @shelter thanks, I will post the question to superuser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a trying out the stuff , I found the easiest way to do this is to use a linux utility to batch convert all docx files into txt files, then do grep with those txt files easily.

Answer (score 2):

i wrote a small bash script, which would help you:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DOCKEY="$@"

function searchdoc(){
 VK1=$(cat "$@" | grep -i "$DOCKEY" | wc -c)
 VK2=$(unzip -c "$@" | grep -i "$DOCKEY" | wc -c)
 let NUM=$VK1+$VK2
 if [ "$NUM" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo $NUM occurences in $@
  echo opening file. 
  gnome-open "$@"
 fi
}

export -f searchdoc
echo searching for $DOCKEY ...
find . -exec bash -c 'searchdoc "{}" 2>/dev/null' \;
```

save it as docfind.sh and you can invoke

```
 $#> docfind.sh searchterm
```

from any folder you want to scan.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! For some reason I couldn't run directly from the terminal. Had to use this instead: /bin/bash docfind.sh searchterm

Answer (score 0):

zgrep might work for you? It usually works in OpenOffice documents, and both are compressed archives containing XML:

```
zgrep "some string" *.xdoc
```

I have no .xdoc files to test this with, but in theory it should work...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it doesn't work with docx, but I have just tested & can confirm that zgrep work fine with txt too.

Comment: also I have tried to save the docx into openOffice format odt, still not working. Have I done anything wrong with  zgrep -In "MSG" *.odt ?

Comment: For anybody else that might want to search .doc files (legacy Word 97 format) instead of docx: `zgrep` works with .doc out of the box, where `docx2txt` does not work. Also it is included with the Git for Windows installation (MinGW64), which is pretty convenient. Great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use zipgrep, which calls grep on all files of a zip archive (which a docx file is).
You might be disappointed with the result, though, as it returns raw content of XML files containing both the text and XML tags.

Answer (score 0):

> save it as docfind.sh and you can invoke

Newbies like me might need to be told that for the .sh script to be executable from any directory, it needs to have the [executable property set](https://www.dslreports.com/faq/linux/7.1_chmod_-_Make_a_file_executable) and be located in /usr/bin or elsewhere in your [Path](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux).

I was able to set up the nemo file manager in Linux Mint to open a terminal from any folder's context menu ([information here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=215405)).